# pip error code 1 when installing javabridge

Tags: python, macos, weka, java-bridge-method

I'm trying to install weka python wrapper and i find out that first i have to install `javabridge` package. but when i'm trying to install it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/ts/vm7w_pd55xscxfb6x9q_gbrr0000gn/T/pip-build-rx5vuvku/javabridge/setup.py", line 155
    except OSError, e:
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ts/vm7w_pd55xscxfb6x9q_gbrr0000gn/T/pip-build-rx5vuvku/javabridge

i'm running mac os el capitan.

Comment: You must be using Python 3 where this syntax is invalid. The module must've been written for Python 2.

Comment: i'd try it with with python 2 but result is the same.

Comment: "you'd try" or "you tried"?

Comment: Yes, the library works only with Python 2, see [requirements](http://pythonhosted.org/python-weka-wrapper/#requirements).

Comment: There is an [experimental Python3 version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-weka-wrapper3) of the library available now.

Answer (score 0):

At this stage, you need Python 2.7 and at most javabridge 1.0.11 for the python-weka-wrapper library (1.0.14 does not work!). You can install javabridge 1.0.11 as follows:

```
sudo pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/j/javabridge/javabridge-1.0.11.tar.gz
```

Comment: javabridge 1.0.14 can be used now as well.